# fopen is not working with softlink

Tags: c, fopen, symlink, chroot

Linux- Red Hat

I am running my binary with chroot in `/var/ROOT/` location
now there is a soft link  between two files

```
ln -s /usr/local/rmgr.txt /var/ROOT/usr/local/rmgr.txt

ll /usr/local/rmgr.txt

prw-r--r--    1 root     root            39 Nov 25 12:04 /usr/local/rmgr.txt

ll /var/ROOT/usr/local/rmgr.txt

lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           39 Nov 25 12:04 /var/ROOT/usr/local/rmgr.txt -> /usr/local/rmgr.txt
```

in my binary I have used function fopen

```
fopen("/usr/local/rmgr.txt","r")
```

but some how not getting this file !

```
Error Opening File : /usr/local/rmgr.txt.
```

Answer (score 4):

Softlink is not much more than a small text file containing a path to a referenced file. It means, that softlink can not point outside of chroot() jail (by definition). The referred path will be read out of it and interpreted inside the chroot().

Hardlinks and bind mounts are special filesystem/kernel entities, so they can be used for cross-chroot() file access.

Comment: ln: cannot create hard link `/var/ROOT/usr/local/rmgr.txt' to `/usr/local/rmgr.txt': Invalid cross-device link

Comment: Are those on the same filesystem? Probably not, I would imagine (different disks or partitions). Thus, you are left with "mount --bind" (this always works, but operates on directories, not individual files).

Comment: mount: /usr/local/ is not a block device

Comment: Why wouldn't you start by carefully studying the mount(8) man page first?